# Twig multi dimensional array - Can't access values

Tags: twig

I have a multidimensional array, but for some reason my twig is not responding with the array values.

Below is my twig Dump

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    object(App\Models\Entities\Strategy\CriticalSuccessFactor)[5]
      private int 'csfId' => int 26
      private iterable 'kpis' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => 
            object(App\Models\Entities\Strategy\KeyPerformanceIndicator)[10]
              ...
  1 => 
    object(App\Models\Entities\Strategy\CriticalSuccessFactor)[11]
      private int 'csfId' => int 27
      private iterable 'kpis' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => 
            object(App\Models\Entities\Strategy\KeyPerformanceIndicator)[12]
```

I did find this link, but it did not answer my question.

[Multidimensional Array in Twig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38492062/multidimensional-array-in-twig)

Below is a respresentation of the array data I am working with

```
csfs[
    private int 'csfId' => int 26
    
    'kpis' => [
        private int 'kpiId' => int 42
    
        'objectives' => [
          private int 'objectivesId' => int 40
        ]
    ] 
]
```

when I am outputting the variable with twig I get nothing.

Here's my Twig:

```
{% for csf in csfs %}
    {% for kpi in csf.kpis %}
        <p> kpi ID : {{ kpi.kpiId }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

{{ csf.csfId }} works. It prints the ID.

I can get the first array values no problem. But I cannot access kpis array

Comment: @DarkBee I've updated the question. Var Dump then the array and then the output code for twig

Comment: Ok that is giving some more information. So as I said in my previous comment, does the entity `CriticalSuccessFactor` has a method `getKpis` which is public?

Comment: @DarkBee thank you, it does yes. The function is getKeyPerformanceIndicators

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As seen in the [documentation](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/templates.html#variables) from `twig`,

> For convenience’s sake foo.bar does the following things on the PHP
> layer:
>
> ```
> check if foo is an array and bar a valid element;
> if not, and if foo is an object, check that bar is a valid property;
> if not, and if foo is an object, check that bar is a valid method (even if bar is the constructor - use __construct() instead);
> if not, and if foo is an object, check that getBar is a valid method;
> if not, and if foo is an object, check that isBar is a valid method;
> if not, and if foo is an object, check that hasBar is a valid method;
> if not, return a null value.
> ```
>
> Twig also supports a specific syntax for accessing items on PHP
> arrays, foo['bar']:
>
> ```
> check if foo is an array and bar a valid element;
> if not, return a null value.
> ```

So you have two options here:

1. Adjust the model `CriticalSuccessFactor`

Either you could rename the method `getKeyPerformanceIndicators` to `getKpis` or add a method `getKpis` which just references `getKeyPerformanceIndicators`

```php
public function getKpis() {
    return $this->getKeyPerformanceIndicators();
}
```

2. Adjust your template and call the method `getKeyPerformanceIndicators`directly rather than let `twig` magically decide the method

```html
{% for kpi in csf.getKeyPerformanceIndicators%}
   ...
{% endfor %}
```