# Loop through multidimensional Array with a variable as a property for another variable

Tags: loops, symfony, twig

I need to loop through an multidimensional array in twig.

//EDIT: I still haven't found the solution, i tried the suggestion with attribute, but it did not work.. here you can see the whole code plus error message, maybe someone can help me. I really try to unterstand the problem, but every attempt at a solution fails :/

First i have the array `category` with different strings.
The strings are user-defined, so they are different depending on the user. E.g.: `Car`, `Food`, `Sport`

The second array `array` is multidimensional an looks like this:

```
array(12) {
  ["01"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["Food"]=>float(861)
    ["Car"]=>float(300)
    ["Sport"]=>float(80)
  }
  ["02"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["Food"]=>float(12)
    ["Car"]=>float(199)
    ["Sport"]=>int(0)
  }
  ["03"]=>
  array(3) {
   ["Food"]=>int(0)
    ["Car"]=>int(0)
    ["Sport"]=>float(80)
  }
… 9 more
```

My Twig Code looks like this

```
           {% for category in categorys %}
           <tr>
                <th>{{category}}</th>
                 
                 {% for line in array %}  
                    <td> {{ attribute(line, category) }} </td
                 {% endfor %}

            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
```

The final table should look like this:

| Food   | 861           | 300   | 80            |

| Car   | 12           | 199   |0          |

| Sport   | 0            | 0  | 80        |

When i use the attribute functions the errormessage is:
**Illegal offset type in isset or empty**

**TypeError
in C:\xampp\htdocs\MMM2\vendor\twig\twig\src\Extension\CoreExtension.php (line 1437)

-->  if (((\is_array($object) || $object instanceof \ArrayObject) && (isset($object[$arrayItem]) || \array_key_exists($arrayItem, (array) $object)))            || ($object instanceof ArrayAccess && isset($object[$arrayItem]))**

How can i use the variable category in this context?
Maybe someone can help me,
I don't know how to continue..
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You said you tried using attribute, but it didn't work. Please add that code as well, what didn't work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access dynamic variable names in twig?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24697313/how-to-access-dynamic-variable-names-in-twig)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not totally sure what you're after and I'm not totally sure what your data structure looks like. But if your data looks like this:

```php
$this->render('foo.html', [
    'categories' => [ 'Food', 'Car', 'Sport' ],
    'values' => [
        [ 'Food' => 861, 'Car' => 300, 'Sport' => 80 ],
        [ 'Food' => 12, 'Car' => 199, 'Sport' => 0 ]
    ]
]);
```

Something like this should work:

```
<table>
    {% for category in categories %}
        <tr>
            <th>{{ category }}</th>
            {% for line in values %}
                <td>{{ attribute(line, category) }}</td>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

It should render this:

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Food</th>
        <td>861</td>
        <td>12</td>
    </tr>
    ...
</table>
```

Comment: My problem is that my data looks like this: 

array(12) {
  ["01"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["Food"]=>float(861)
    ["Car"]=>float(300)
    ["Sport"]=>float(80)
  }
  ["02"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["Food"]=>float(12)
    ["Car"]=>float(199)
    ["Sport"]=>int(0)
  }
… 10 more

So there is 1 array with12 arrays in it. And in every array is an array with X elements (in our example Food, Car and Sport). Each Element(key) has one value. And i cant figure out how i can get this values in a loop.

I hope now it is more understandable. 


/EDIT: The array is now in the original question

Comment: Why would that be a problem? Works as is - [demo](https://twigfiddle.com/qc190b)

Comment: @Bjorn I would add the `default` filter to account for undefined keys though, which could be the actual problem of OP

Comment: @DarkBee Based on the information LittleEast provided it shouldn't be necessary, but could be yes. LittleEast, are you getting any errors? If so, please provide them. I'm afraid we won't be able to help you any further without.

Comment: So the error message is: "Illegal offset type in isset or empty"
Iam very sure its because of my array. Its not like in your example, because there is one Dimension more. Like:
 'values' => [
        '01' => [ 'Food' => 861, 'Car' => 300, 'Sport' => 80 ],
        '02' => [ 'Food' => 12, 'Car' => 199, 'Sport' => 0 ]
...]

Comment: So there is another question on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38492062/multidimensional-array-in-twig
He had a similar problem but the difference is: he know the names of his keys.. so he can use the solutione like  {{ value.name }}, {{ value.quantity }}, {{ value.price }}...
My keynames like food, sport etc.. are different from case to case..

Comment: @LittleEast I understand that your keynames are dynamic. That is why we're using `{{ attribute(your_array, keyname) }}` to access them. I cannot reproduce the error you are getting, even when I add the name the keys "01"/"02"/ etc. That is not an extra dimension btw, its just a associative array iso a regular array. As long as your category names exactly match (pay attention to capitals) the names in the values array, my answer should work.

Comment: I added some Information in the Main question. The Capitals etc are Right.. but it still dont work:/

Answer (score 0):

Okay guys, thanks to everyone, especially to Bjorn for the help.
I finally found my problem because of a zoomtalk with a friend of mine who is more experienced than me in php.

My problem was the category-array.. This array saved not only texts but entire objects.. so i must add .name to category, that i get the Strings "Food, Car, Sport"...

The answer looks like this

```
<table>
    {% for category in categories %}
        <tr>
            <th>{{ category }}</th>
            {% for line in values %}
                <td>{{ attribute(line, category.name) }}</td>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Thanks again for your effort!